# String Search for a Longer String Partly Matches the Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a products table with barcode information. Some scanned barcodes include extra information besides the box barcode information.

My box barcode is 12345.

Scanned barcode is 991234599.

If the scanned barcode would be shorter than the barcode I'd be searching like

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE BARCODE LIKE '%123%'
```

it would give me the barcodes including the string 123
In my case string is longer than the barcode, I couldnt find a way to search something like

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE '991234599' LIKE BARCODE (THIS DOESN'T WORK)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you append the wildcard character to the start and end of the column value then  `like` will work. Performance will be horrible, but then it always is with `like` and a leading wildcard.

```
SELECT *
FROM PRODUCTS
WHERE '991234599' LIKE '%' + BARCODE + '%'
```

Comment: Thank for your reply but unfortunately it's not working on MS SQL Server

Comment: @TuranKilic . . . This should do what you want.  Here is a db<>fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9d3b82c02ca5a201dbc7d567f376fba5.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried it and expecting it to work but it's not working on MS SQL server

Comment: @TuranKilic . . . Something is wrong with your testing -- perhaps bad characters or you misstated the question.  This answers the question that you asked here.  That is why I added a db<>fiddle.  This does work in SQL Server.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes you're right, the column I try to test is CHAR type, after I trim it, it worked. Sorry for the any inconveniences.