# SQL LIKE using the same row value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm wondering how can I use a row value as a variable for my like statement? For example

```
ID | PID  | DESCRIPTION
1  | 4124 | Hi4124
2  | 2451 | Test
3  | 1467 | Hello
4  | 9642 | Me9642
```

I have a table above, I want to return IDs 1 and 4 since `DESCRIPTION` contains `PID`. 
I'm thinking it would be `SELECT * from TABLE WHERE DESCRIPTION LIKE '%PID%'` but I can't get it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String Search for a Longer String Partly Matches the Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61631426/string-search-for-a-longer-string-partly-matches-the-column)

Comment: The idea is same but I want to search the whole table that's matching 2 row values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CONCAT()` to assemble the matching pattern, as in:

```
select *
from t
where description like concat('%', PID, '%')
```

Answer (score 2):

We could also try using `CHARINDEX` here:

```
SELECT ID, PID, DESCRIPTION
FROM yourTable
WHERE CHARINDEX(PID, DESCRIPTION) > 0;
```

### Demo

Note that I assume in the demo that the `PID` column is actually text, and not a numeric column.  If `PID` be numeric, we might have to first use a cast in order to use `CHARINDEX` (or any of the methods given in the other answers).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CONCAT` SQL function

```sql
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE DESCRIPTION LIKE CONCAT('%', PID, '%')
```

Comment: Seems identical to the answer already provided by The Impaler?